# Addthis widget in fixed element - position error?

Tags: css, html, fixed, addthis

I am using addthis as a vertical toolbox with the popup to be displayed on hover in a **fixed** element.
But when scrolling, the popup is displayed somewhere else. I tried using configs of offset top and left, but there were of no use. Is there any solution for this ???

DEMO here ----> http://jsfiddle.net/vaakash/QzjxR/1/embedded/result/

Comment: By "position:fixed" the the "div.atfixed" is positioned relative to the viewport/browser windows/canvas which may or maynot be the html or body element depending upon the user agent/browser. So when you scroll, the :hover peseudo class still places it as above. So it is acting as it should. Since I can not find the :hover code, I suspect you would have to change you could there so that the popup is placed relative to the div.atfixed - https://www.addthis.com/help/menu-offset-and-delay - http://jsfiddle.net/7vqAE/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried using the code using jQuery and fairly satisfied my needs. So. here i used the on "mousemove" event to position the popup and it did worked.

```
$('.addthis_button_compact, .addthis_bubble_style').mousemove(function(e){
    $('#at15s').css({
        'top': e.pageY - 200 ,
        'left': e.pageX - 200
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is no fix, according to the **AddThis** people.

> This happens because we don't
>   recalculate the position of the DIV
>   after the menu is invoked. What I
>   would do is disable the compact menu
>   and set the button to only use the
>   expanded (full) menu, which is auto
>   centered.

So change `<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>` to `<a class="addthis_button_expanded"></a>`

http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=24157

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation where I had a div that dynamicly changed from normal to fixed positioning based on the scroll position (it was a sticky menu halfway on the page).

In the end I fixed it with this code:

```
// begin Fix for the AddThis menu positioning..
$(".sharing").bind("mouseenter", function (e) {
  var isSticky = $(".sharing").hasClass("sticky");
  var buttonPos = $(".addthis_button_compact").offset();
  addthis_config.ui_offset_top = isSticky ? buttonPos.top - 9 : 0;
});
// config for the AddThis menu positioning, needs to be in the global scope..
var addthis_config = {  ui_offset_top: 0 }
```

See [AddThis menu offset](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381243-menu-offset-delay) for help on the `addthis_config` parameter.